# Ionic keyboard plugin native.keyboardshow and native.keyboardhide events not firing on Android 4.x

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Ionic keyboard plugin native.keyboardshow and native.keyboardhide events not firing when soft keyboard mode is set to "adjustNothing". The two events broadcast event data only when when the mode is changed to "adjustPan" but unfortunately we cannot use adjutsPan for this app.
Note: the app is not running in full screen mode which is known to be  causing a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately because Android doesn't natively provide the keyboard size like iOS does, the way the keyboard plugin works is by comparing view resizes, so adjustNothing won't work because there's nothing to compare.

If you really *have* to use adjustNothing there are still ways to try and guess when the keyboard is showing on Android from javascript, but it involves a fair amount of edge cases.  You'll have to track focus/blur and things like the [Cordova backbutton](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton) event to determine when the keyboard is showing/not showing.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issue. Have posted here on the IONIC Keyboard plugin Git but nothing yet.

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard/issues/86#issuecomment-145508828